# How can I introspect the "shared subtree" mount flags for a particular mount?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

Under Linux, the [shared subtree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) flags control how a mountpoint is shared with parent and child [mount namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/).  These flags include `MS_SHARED`, `MS_PRIVATE`, and `MS_SLAVE`.  How can one see which of these flags are set on a particular mountpoint?

These flags don't show up in the output of `mount` or in `/proc/mounts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `/proc/self/mountinfo`. For instance, in one of my systemd-based Ubuntu VMs `/` is shared (systemd enforces it at boot time):

```
$ cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep ' / / '
22 0 8:1 / / rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/disk/by-uuid/e176bae0-84a5-4bd2-b968-e809e902488c rw,data=ordered
```